# Why does Timestamp in DataRow is not auto generated?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, datarow, datacolumn

I am trying to do a bulk insert into DB, my previous attempt was to use dapper for bulk insert but it was horrible, so i attempted with clean ADO.NET
approach

I Generate datatable and populate it from list of items:

```
  using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(VoucherConnectionManager.connectionString))
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand("SET FMTONLY ON; SELECT * FROM Voucher; SET FMTONLY OFF;", cn);
                    var dt = new DataTable();

                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

                    foreach (var itm in voucherList)
                    {
                        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                        row["VoucherUid"] = itm.Uid;
                        row["ClientUid"] = itm.ClientUid;
                        row["BatchUid"] = itm.BatchUid;
                        row["CardNo"] = itm.CardNo;
                        row["Origin"] = itm.Origin;
                        row["VoucherCreateDate"] = itm.VoucherCreateDate;
                        row["State"] = itm.State;
                        //row["LastTimeStamp"] = DateTime.Now;

                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn))
                    {
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Voucher";
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                    }
                    cn.Dispose();
                }
```

problem here is that i am getting following error :

> ```
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.NoNullAllowedException' occurred in MasterRepositorys.dll
>
> Additional information: Column 'LastTimeStamp' does not allow nulls.
> ```

LastTimeStamp is a timestamp column, why dont it get auto generated? What have i done wrong?

**EDIT
TABLE DEF:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Voucher](
    [VoucherUid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ClientUid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [BatchUid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CardNo] [nvarchar](13) NOT NULL,
    [CycleUid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [CycleCreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [VoucherCreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastTimeStamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [int] NULL,
    [Origin] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OrderRef] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
    [State] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Voucher] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [VoucherUid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Is it really a timestamp (aka rowversion) field and not just datetime? If it's datetime you'll need to have a default value for it, or give it in your insert clause

Comment: Can you show the actual table definition as a `CREATE TABLE` statement? Please note that `timestamp` in SQL Server has a specific meaning which is unrelated to time.

Comment: added table definition

Comment: as error suggests you can not insert null values in that column. looking at your table and requirement you may need to allow null values in your column.

Comment: If you're wanting to store a date/time value, you've picked the wrong type. See [`rowversion` (a.k.a. `timestamp`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i changed timestamp to rowversion, still same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column "LastTimeStamp" is part of your DataTable and therefore a value is expected. It is part of your DataTable because you select all rows and columns from the table

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SET FMTONLY ON; SELECT * FROM Voucher; SET FMTONLY OFF;", cn);
...
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
```

Do you need to load all values to the DataTable before bulk inserting? I guess not. Therefore you can solve the problem by avoiding the select and `dt.Load` and instead add only the columns you want to bulk insert to the table like that:

```
table.Columns.Add("VoucherUid", typeof (...));
```

Alternatively I think you can still use the select but only select the columns you will also insert.

Comment: ended up by select only necesarry columns

Answer (score 0):

Column in sql table with timestamp datatype is auto generated , don't insert values in it explicitly  and whenever record is inserted in table it will be populated with current timestamp

Comment: Where do i insert timestamps in table?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to below to mention that `LastTimeStamp` is a `TimeStamp` type else essentially you are saying `LastTimeStamp is null` and so getting the error.

```
            foreach (var itm in voucherList)
            {
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row["VoucherUid"] = itm.Uid;
                row["ClientUid"] = itm.ClientUid;
                row["BatchUid"] = itm.BatchUid;
                row["CardNo"] = itm.CardNo;
                row["Origin"] = itm.Origin;
                row["VoucherCreateDate"] = itm.VoucherCreateDate;
                row["State"] = itm.State;
                row["LastTimeStamp"] = SqlDbType.Timestamp; //Here

                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```